# Deploying ASP.NET Core Web API to Azure - with Azure Key Vault and SQL Database dependency

Tags: deployment, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-appservice, microsoft-identity-platform

I was able to deploy my Web API to Azure. I had to configure for 'Azure Key Vault', 'Azure SQL DB' and 'Microsoft Identity platform' before deployment as they were dependencies.

I configured Azure Key Vault and while configuring for SQL database, I selected the option to save connection string value in 'Azure Key Vault' instead of 'Azure app settings' (please see screenshot below).

[image]

When i press configure for 'Microsoft identify platform', the page shows loading symbol but never finshes and doesnt show any tenant id or details for configuration. Please see screenshot below.

[image]

So I had to ignore configuring Microsoft Identity Platform for now.

I was able to deploy the app to Azure, but when I try accessing the Azure endpoint, I get an error

> HTTP ERROR 500 (Trouble retrieving data from database).

Log file message below while accessing the Azure endpoint:

> An error occurred using the connection to database 'databasename' on server 'servername'.
>
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'ItemApp.Infrastructure.Repository.ItemDBContext'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections...

Can anyone point where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Check to see if your database engine can handle remote connections:**

- Start > All Programs > SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > SQL
  Server Surface Area Configuration
- Click on Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections
- Select the instance that is having a problem > Database Engine >
  Remote Connections
- Enable local and remote connections
- Restart instance

2. **Check if your SQL server services is up and running properly:**

- Go to All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL
  Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services
- Check to make sure SQL Server service status is Running.
- In addition, ensure that your remote server is in the same network.
- Run sqlcmd -L to ascertain if your server is included in your network list.

3. **You may need to create an exception on the firewall for the SQL Server instance and port you are using:**

- Start > Run > Firewall.cpl
- Click on exceptions tab
- Add sqlservr.exe (typically located in C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\MSSQL\Bin, check your installs for
  the actual folder path) and port (default is 1433)
- Check your connection string as well

Please check the MSFT Document to troubleshoot the error: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thank you. I was able to bring up the application and hit the endpoints successfully. But only if I remove Azure key vault dependency (both while publishing and in the code). And use my connection string in appsettings. json instead.

Comment: Adding Azure key vault,  Gives "(provider: SNI_PN11, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): The system cannot find the file specified.at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection" when deployed to Azure. Works locally. Earlier it was error: 40.  Any suggestions on this?